# Run Time Check Failure #2 when trying to make an Array of Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, runtime-error

I get this Runtime Error with this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 27

struct CountABC
{
    char c;
    int n;
}typedef CountABC_t;

char commonestLetter(char* filename)
{
    CountABC_t ABC[SIZE];
    int i,count=0;
    char cha;
    for (cha='A', i=0 ; i <=SIZE ; cha++,i++)
    {
        ABC[i].c= cha;
        ABC[i].n = 0;
    }
    //printf("%c",ABC[3].c);

}


void main()
{
    char* str = "ABBA GADDA LOLLAL";
    char str2[SIZE];
    char ch;
    FILE* f = fopen("input.txt","w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Cannot Find Any File!!");
        return;
    }
    fputs(str,f);
    fclose(f);

    ch = commonestLetter("input.txt");

}
```

I guess its something with the code inside the for loop but havent realized whats wrong with it.

It says "stack around the Variable ABC was corrupted" 
Thanks

Comment: You don't have the return value for the `commonestLetter(char* filename)`, and the for loop seems ok. Can you post more specific corrupting messages?

Comment: Compiler warnings are not for fun. Enable and pay heed to them. First get your code free of warnings.

Comment: The RTC feature was designed to help you find bugs like `i <=SIZE`, stack buffer overflow is pretty nasty UB.

Comment: 0 to SIZE is 28 elements not 27 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you messed up to declare the array of struct. Try to change the array declaration `CountABC_t ABC[SIZE]` to `CountABC_t ABC[SIZE+5]` at commonestLetter method.

**Explain**

You declare struct array as `CountABC_t ABC[27]` that means you can set value `ABC[0-26]`. But later in the for loop, you try to set `ABC[27].c` which index is greater than 26, so that gives you `run time error.` To solve the issue, you need to declare the array with size > 27.

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help you.

Comment: @alk, 5 is just a random number mate, he can declare anything greater than `SIZE`